# Mkdirs Xamarin does not work on Android 6.0

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a pretty simple android application written on Xamarin and running on two different virtual devices: on Genymotion Google Nexus 5 - Android 5.1.0 and Genymotion Google Nexus 6P - Android 6.0.0. After some debugging I've discovered that [Mkdirs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Java.IO.File.Mkdirs()/) does not create the directory on my virtual device. How can I get the reason why? My guess is that my app does not have permissions to save the files or create directories on device's external storage even though `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is set to true. Are there some changes in Android 6 permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 6.0 introduced Runtime permissions. In addition to declaring the permission on your manifest, you need to request the permission from the user at runtime.

More info and tutorials here: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

For Xamarin specific information: https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/